Recursion proposition: If $n=m$, show that $a_n = a_m$
I am reading Tao's book (Analysis I), where he states recursion proposition (1 chapter, Peano axioms).

Proposition For a natural number $n$, let's assume that there exists some function $f_n: \mathbf N \rightarrow \mathbf N$. Take some natural number $c$ and define $a_0 := c$, and for any natural number $n$, we define $a_{S(n)} := f_n(a_n)$ (note: $S(n)$ refers to the successor function). Show that for any natural number $n$, $a_n$ is uniquely defined.

Author's proof. We use induction. We first observe that this procedure gives a single value to $a_0$, namely c. (None of the other definitions $a_{S(n)} := f_n(a_n)$ will redefine the value of $a_0$, because of Axiom 2.3.) Now suppose inductively that the procedure gives a single value to $a_n$. Then it gives a single value to $a_{S(n)}$, namely $a_{S(n)} := f_n(a_n)$. (None of the other definitions $a_{(S(n)} := f_m(a_m)$ will redefine the value of $a_{S(n)}$, because of Axiom 2.4.) This completes the induction, and so $a_n$ is defined for each natural number $n$, with a single value assigned to each $a_n$.
My questions are:

In the base step, how can we show that for any $m$, if $m=0$ then $a_0 = a_m$?
In the inductive step, how can we show that if $n=m$, then $a_n = a_m$? (I am assuming this information would be needed to show that $a_{S(n)} = a_{S(m)}$)

It would've been easy to answer both of those questions if it could be shown that we can  define function from $\mathbf N$ to $\{a_n \mid n \in \mathbf N\}$. But since this is exactly what we are trying to prove via this proposition, we cannot use that fact. So what am I missing?

The first question really depends on what axioms you have, but if $m=0,$ then by definition $a_m=a_0.$ That is just basic. How you prove it formally, again, depends on all the definitions.

The specifics of the proof will depend on details only in the book - there are lots of essentially equivalent ways to axiomatize first-order logic.

@ThomasAndrews Only Peano axioms; and unfortunately there is not much details in the book with regards to this specific proposition (the whole proof presented in the book was written above)

There are axioms to first order logic and axioms for propositional calculus that are not considered part of Peano, but arre structurally necessary for Peano postulates to allow you to deduce anything. Of course. in sttandard first order logic, you can't even talk about functions or sequences. Basically, you should just assume it is true.

@ThomasAndrews So just to confirm that I understand you correctly: there are multiple axioms to first order logic and propositional calculus which can be stated differently in different texts, and to answer both of my questions we'd need to understand which exact formulation of those axioms is used. Am I correct? (as a side note: in the textbook none of those axioms are mentioned, so I guess it's just implicitly assumed)

Roughly. Additionally, even then, you can't simply write about functions in first or second order logic with Peano axioms. There are ways to encode functions in second order logic, but it is highly complicated. But in all basic versions of logic, if $m=n$ then $a_m=a_n,$  and $f(m)=f(n).$ That is the ultimate inherent meaning of equality.

Of course, you have to be careful. If you write $2=1+1,$ you can't say simply $5\cdot 2\cdot 3=5\cdot 1+1\cdot 3.$ You have to replace $5\cdot (1+1)\cdot 3.$ This is a difficulty of  our binary operation notation - they are really functions, but we write them weirdly. If we wrote them as functions, they wouldn't have this problem.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks for your feedback. Please, convert it into an answer, I will accept it.
